# Remove Lines that Match from File

Tags: python, bash-scripting

I have a file that contains various dates and IPs that I need to do a daily purge of. The file format is:

```
# 2018-02-21 11:31:37 - user1 - This is a test.
1.1.1.1
# 2018-02-21 11:32:30 - user1 - This is also a test.
2.2.2.2
# 2018-03-06 21:12:44 - user2 - Another comment.
3.3.3.3
```

On a daily basis I want to remove any comment line + the IP below it that is older than 30 days. For that, I can easily do a bash variable of "LAST_MONTH=`date --date="-30 days" +%Y-%m-%d`" and I can get the lines easily enough by doing "DELETE=$(cat /var/www/html/ips | grep $DATE -A1)".

From here, I could technically use sed to wipe out the lines such as "sed -i "s/$DELETE/test/g" "$FILE"" but there are hash tags and multiple lines involved so it's not really working for me right now.

What would you recommend as the best way to do this? I don't want to create another temp file if at all possible. I'd also be interested in both bash and Python solutions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some python: warning, I'm pretty new to it.

```python
import io
import datetime

buffer = io.StringIO()
ago = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)
filename = "file"

with open(filename,"r") as f:
    line = f.readline()
    while line:
        if line.startswith("#"):
            date = (line.split())[1]
            if date >= ago.isoformat():
                buffer.write(line)
                line = f.readline()
                buffer.write(line)
        line = f.readline()

with open(filename, "w") as f:
    f.write(buffer.getvalue())
```

Answer (score 1):

requires GNU date, and [`sponge`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/sponge.1.html) from the moreutils package to write back to the same file

```
awk -v ago="$(date -d '30 days ago' '+%F %T')" '
    $1 == "#" && $2" "$3 < ago {getline; next}
    {print}
' file | sponge file
```